# Multiple instances of complex type in same model from Stored Procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework Code First and I have the following scenario, I have a Member model with 2 types of Address, Residence address and Correspondence address. Address is a complex type, so I have 2 instances of the same complex type in the same model. I read this from here:
[Entity framework complex type multiple instances in one model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311680/entity-framework-complex-type-multiple-instances-in-one-model), but there is no stored procedure involved.
My case is pretty much the same but using Store Procedure.

Here are my models and the query used in the store procedure.

Address Complext Type:

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public AddressType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Member Class:

```
public class Member
{
    public Address ResidenceAddress { get; set; }
    public Address CorrespondenceAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Method Calling the Stored Procedure:

```
public Member GetMember(string memberId)
{
    using (var entityContext = new AmigosContext())
    {
        var sqlParams = new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("memberId", memberId), 
        };
        var result = entityContext.Database.SqlQuery<MemberInfoEnhanced>("EXEC GetMember @MemberId ", sqlParams);

        return result.FirstOrDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Sql query inside the Stored procedure:

```
SELECT  gcar.AddressLine1 AS ResidentAddressLine1
     , gcar.AddressLine2 AS ResidentAddressLine2
     , gcityr.Name AS ResidentCity
     , gcar.State AS ResidentState
     , gcar.Zip AS ResidentZip
     , gcountry.ISOAlpha AS ResidentCountryISOCode
     , gcar.AddressTypeId AS ResidentAddressTypeId
     , gcac.AddressLine1 AS CorrespondenceAddressLine1
     , gcac.AddressLine2 AS CorrespondenceAddressLine2
     , gcityc.Name AS CorrespondenceCity
     , gcac.State AS CorrespondenceState
     , gcac.Zip AS CorrespondenceZip
     , gcac.AddressTypeId AS CorrespondenceAddressTypeId

FROM Member pm WITH (NOLOCK)ON pm.MemberId = pme.MemberId
       LEFT JOIN Generic_ContactAddress gcar ON gcar.ContactBaseId = pm.ContactBaseId -- get resident address
                                                    AND gcar.AddressTypeId = 2 --Physical Address
       LEFT JOIN Generic_Country gcountry ON gcountry.CountryId = gcar.CountryId -- to get the ISOAlpha code
       LEFT JOIN Generic_City gcityr ON gcityr.CityId = gcar.CityId --to get the resident CityName
       LEFT JOIN Generic_ContactAddress gcac ON gcac.ContactBaseId = pm.ContactBaseId -- to get correspondence address
                                                    AND gcac.AddressTypeId = 1 --Correspondence (Mailing) Address
       LEFT JOIN Generic_City gcityc ON gcityc.CityId = gcar.CityId --to get the correspondence CityName
     
WHERE pm.MemberId = @MemberId
```

Is there any way to map the different address columns into the different complex type?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but in EF code first don't you have to set the foreign properties as `virtual`? ie `public virtual Address ResidenceAddress { get; set; }`